# No advanced settings option in router

Tags: network, routing

How can I configure NAT Settings when my router doesn't have advanced settings option.
[image: My beetle 450bx1]

Comment: Get a different router?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it was a router you owned, you could look in to third party firmwares, but since it appears to be an ISP's router/DSL modem, your best bet is to buy a different router for yourself and treat the ISP's router as a WAN device.

Comment: ok thanks for the advice. I'll buy a new one soon.

Comment: Good advice for any case. ISPs *always* have a back door into their gateway devices. Trusting that device as part of your internal network inherently requires that you trust all of the ISP's employees to not mess with it.